# Flickering of dataTableOutput when manipulating with sliderValues

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

In a shiny app I add reactive values to a datatable with `sliderInput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("a", "A", min = 0, max = 3, value = 0, width = "250px"),
  titlePanel("Sliders"),
  dataTableOutput("sliderValues", width="450px")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(
      Name = "A", 
      Value = as.character(c(input$a)), 
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = Value)
    
    return(df)
  })

  
  # Show the values in an HTML table in a wider format----
  output$sliderValues <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(sliderValues(),
                  extensions = c('Buttons'),
                  options = list(
                    dom = 'frtBip',
                    buttons = list(list(extend = 'excel', filename = paste0("myname-", Sys.Date())))
                  )
    )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

By doing so I realized that the table **flickers** each time I move the slider.
What is the reason for this and how can we solve it?

Here is a example of what I am talking about. Note the 3 dots flickering at the middle to end of the gif:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dataTableProxy`, this way only the data will be pushed to the client, instead of recreating the object everytime with the vanilla approach you have. I've also added the `processing=FALSE` to the options so its not creating other messages such as `Processing...`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(tidyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("a", "A", min = 0, max = 3, value = 0, width = "250px"),
  titlePanel("Sliders"),
  DT::DTOutput(outputId = "sliderValues", width="450px")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(
      Name = "A", 
      Value = as.character(c(input$a)), 
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = Value)
    return(df)
  })
  
  
  # Show the values in an HTML table in a wider format----
  output$sliderValues <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(isolate(sliderValues()),
                  extensions = c('Buttons'),
                  options = list(processing=FALSE,
                    dom = 'frtBip',
                    buttons = list(list(extend = 'excel', filename = paste0("myname-", Sys.Date())))
                  )
    )
  })
  
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('sliderValues')
  
  observe({
    replaceData(proxy, sliderValues())
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This looks great. I will try it in a minute. What is the difference between `renderDataTable` vs. `renderDT`? Many thanks.

Comment: shiny has its own `renderDataTable`, `renderDT` is an alias to that but from the `DT` package itself. More info here https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you think I can use the same concept when it is not a sliderValue but a reactive data table that is fill by multiple ` updateRadioGroupButtons`. Anyway I now checked the thing with isolate and proxy.

Comment: yes you can, instead of isolating the one input, you can isolate the first reactive or multiple of them, as per https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html. You can think of isolation as a way of doing stuff without evoking reactivity further down the chain...